SQL Server job fails with error "Execute As Login failed for requested login"
I have a SQL Server account that is set as job owner for one of my SQL Server accounts.
The SQL account has all three SQLAgent permissions in MSDB: Operator, Reader and User.
When I try to run the job it fails with the error:

EXECUTE AS LOGIN' failed for the requested login
'SQLServerJobAdministrator'.  The step failed.

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this error please?

I had this happen for users.  I granted them Read, Write, Execute and update permissions on all objects.  With the Execute as Owner it requires more elevated permissions, I think possibly even owner of the DB, if not owner high enough permissions to be close.  So either remove the Execute AS from the code or you will have to grant higher permissions to the user running the job.

For TSQL job steps the SQL Agent service account will to SQL Server impersonation of the job owner.
So, can you verify that the SQL Agent Service account is a sysadmin and SQLServerJobAdministrator has access to the target database?

Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. The SQL Agent account as sysadmin. I think the job owner needed access to the target database. I've tried running the job using one example and that works. Just need to try with a few other jobs now. Thanks

Job owner needed access to the target database.
